# Two csv files read differently in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have two .csv files with data arranged date-wise. I want to compute the monthly accumulated value for each month and for all the years. While reading the csv files, it reads without any error. However, while computing the monthly accumulated values, for one times series (in one csv file), it is doing it correctly. But, for the other time series, the same code malfunctions. The only difference I notice is, when I read the first csv file (with a 'Date' and 'Value' column, and total no. of rows = 826), the dataframe has 827 rows (last row as nan). This nan thing is not observed for the other csv file.

Please note that my timeseries starts from 06-06-20xx to 01-10-20xx every year from 2008-2014. I am obtaining the monthly accumulated value for each month and then removing the zero values (for months Jan-May and Nov-Dec). When my code runs, for the first csv, I get monthly accumulated values starting from June month of 2008. But, for the second, its starts from January 2008 (and has a non-zero value, which ideally should be zero).

Since I am new in python coding, I cannot figure out where the issue is. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# read the csv file
df_obs = pd.read_csv("..path/first_csv.csv")
df_fore = pd.read_csv("..path/second_csv.csv")

# convert 'Date' column to datetime index
df_obs['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_obs['Date'])
df_fore['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_fore['Date'])


# perform GroupBy operation over monthly frequency
monthly_accumulated_obs = df_obs.set_index('Date').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M'))['Observed'].sum().reset_index()
monthly_accumulated_fore = df_fore.set_index('Date').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M'))['Observed'].sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: maybe you should use something like a try block to check if the row is valid and skip it if its something like nan

Comment: add an example of the two csv in order to make the code reproducible

Comment: Is there any way to upload a csv file here? I don't find any option to upload them here. By looks, both the csv files looks something like: Date Observed
06-06-2008 7.008856392
07-06-2008 4.279864114
08-06-2008 7.106759494
09-06-2008 11.68559165
10-06-2008 8.242029367
11-06-2008 12.84564937
12-06-2008 6.555772215

Comment: I could identify the error here. The malfunction occurred because 'months=df_obs.index.month' was not actually giving the month correctly. The month index is retrieved as 1,2,3,....,12,6,6,6,......6,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,....12,7,7,7,...,7777,1,2,3,..12 (which is wrong. It should come as 6,6,6,...6,7,7,7,...7,7,8,8,8,...9,9,9,...,10,10,10,.... However, I could not solve the problem of indexing the month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes more verbose but explicit solutions work better and are more flexible, so here's an alternative one, using [convtools](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools):

```py
from datetime import date, datetime

from convtools import conversion as c
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table

# generate an ad hoc grouper;
# it's a simple function to be reused further
converter = (
    c.group_by(c.item("Date"))
    .aggregate(
        {
            "Date": c.item("Date"),
            "Observed": c.ReduceFuncs.Sum(c.item("Observed")),
        }
    )
    .gen_converter()
)

# read the stream of prepared rows
rows = (
    Table.from_csv("..path/first_csv.csv", header=True)
    .update(
        Date=c.call_func(
            datetime.strptime, c.col("Date"), "%m-%d-%Y"
        ).call_method("replace", day=1),
        Observed=c.col("Observed").as_type(float),
    )
    .into_iter_rows(dict)
)

# process them
result = converter(rows)
```

Comment: Thanks Nikita Almakov! I don't know where the problem is, but your solution worked.